# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in the ring class field of conductor $p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, complex-multiplication

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, $p$ a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $H_p$ the ring class field of $K$ of conductor $p$, i.e. the abelian extension of $K$ with Galois group isomorphic to the class group of the order of $K$ of conductor $p$. Let $p^*=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p$, so that $p^*\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

By class field theory, it seems known that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})\subseteq H_p$.

Can someone give a hint about why this inclusion should hold?

Comment: Show that the ring class number is even and use the fact that ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{p})$ has conductor $p$ (or $p \infty$) over ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: So you're saying: if $\sqrt{p^*}\in K$, we're done. Suppose that $\sqrt{p^*}\notin K$: then $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is the only quadratic extension of $K$ that ramifies in $p$. Since the ring class number is even, $H_p$ contains a field of degree $2$ over $K$, and so this field must be $K(\sqrt{p^*})$.

Comment: It remains to prove the the ring class number is even

Comment: There's a  formula for ring class numbers going back to Gauss and Dirichlet. You should be able to look it up in Cox's book on primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$.

Comment: Thankyou! I still have one doubt: are we sure that $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is the only possible quadratic extension of $K$ that is ramified at most at $p$? I don't think that this is true, as one can sometimes have that the Hilbert class field $H_1$ of $K$ contains an extension of degree $2$ of $K$, and $H_1$ is always contained in $H_p$. In this case the parity of the ring class number seems not enough in order to conclude...

Comment: But ok, one can still say that the degree of the extension $[H_p:H_1]$ is even, using the ring class formula from Cox. So maybe the question is: are we sure that the only quadratic extension of $H_1$ that ramifies at most at $p$ is $H_1(\sqrt{p^*})$?

Comment: No. But we know it is the only one over the rationals, which is all you need.

Comment: I don't get your argument...could you explain a bit more? I thought about this: the ring class number is even, so there exists a quadratic extension $F$ of $K$ contained in $H_p$. $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois with Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $F$ is a biquadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence it contains two other fields $K_1$ and $K_2$, on which $p$ must ramify. But still I can't see why $p$ must be the only prime ramifying in one of those fields.

Comment: Conductor $p$ implies that only $p$ ramifies in the ring class field. Thus $p$ is the only finite prime ramifying in one of the the quadratic subextensions (if $p$ is not ramified in $K$).

Comment: Conductor $p$ implies that the only primes ramifying in $H_p/K$ are the primes of $K$ dividing $p$. But the primes dividing the discriminant of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ ramify in $K$, and so ramify also in $H_p$. If $p$ is not ramified in $K$, $p$ ramifies in the other quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, but why can't some other prime dividing the discriminant of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ ramify in these extensuions?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the mess - the problem was that the result is "obvious" (see below) but that I wanted to avoid using the Artin isomorphisms.

A normal extension $L/K$ of a quadratic number field is a ring class field if and only if $G = $Gal$(L/{\mathbb Q})$ is a group extension of an abelian group by a group of order $2$ and if the nontrivial automorphism of $K/{\mathbb Q}$ acts as $-1$ on Gal$(L/K)$ (see Bruckner [Charakterisierung der galoisschen Zahlkörper, deren zerlegte Primzahlen durch binäre quadratische Formen gegeben sind. Math. Nachr. 32, 317-326 (1966)]; this is essentlially Artin at work since $\sigma$ acts as $-1$ on the class group of a quadratic number field). Since ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$ is
contained in the ray class field modulo $p\infty$ of ${\mathbb Q}$,
$L = K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in the ray class field modulo $p\infty$ of $K$ ("translation"), hence in the ray class field modulo $p$ of $K$ since $K$ is complex quadratic. And since the nontrivial automorphism $\sigma$ of $K/{\mathbb Q}$ acts trivially on Gal$(L/K)$ ($\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} = \tau = \tau^{-1}$ since the extension is elementary abelian), it is a ring class field.

I still believe that there's a simple argument that works without Bruckner.

Comment: Why do we have that the ray class field of conductor $p\infty$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in the ring class field $H_p$ of conductor $p$ of $K$? Of course we have that the ray class field of conductor $p\infty$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in the ray class field $K_p$ of conductor $p$ of $K$, but I don't see why it should be contained in $H_p$.  In general, $Gal(K_p/H_p)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Of course, once we have this inclusion, we can conclude easily

Comment: Typo: It's the other way round. Ring class groups are ray class groups.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Keep the notation of my previous comment. With your first two sentences we find that $k\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)\subseteq K_p$, and we know that $H_p\subseteq K_p$. Why this implies that $k\subseteq H_p$? I mean, with your argument the only thing I see is that $k\subseteq K_p$. Also if you take $kK$, this is a priori a quadratic extension of $K$ contained in $K_p$, not in $H_p$. The fact that the ring class group modulo $p$ in $K$ (i.e $Gal(H_p/K)$) is even, implies that $H_p/K$ has a quadratic extension...but why this extension must be $kK$?

Comment: I have seen you edited the answer. I think that there is something going on that I don't know. For example, I just know what ring class fields are for imaginary quadratic fields, I don't know how they're defined for $\mathbb{Q}$ for example. Also, I'm not sure of what  the "transfer theorem of class field theory" is.  If maybe you know a place where I can find some material about this, please tell me. Otherwise, thankyou very much, I don't want to bother you more.

Comment: I can't find an english version of Bruckner, but I think that the result is equivalent to Theorem 9.18 of Cox, "Primes of the form...". It says that any generalized dihedral extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in a ring class field of $K$. Now, we have that $L=K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is generalized dihedral over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence contained in a ring class field. But following the proof of Cox, the conductor of the ring class field that contains $L$ has to be enlarged, being $pd$ where $d$ is the discriminant of $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Since $L$ is in the ray class field modulo $p$, we can eliminate $d$?

Comment: If $E/F$ is an abelian extension with conductor ${\mathfrak f}$, then $KE/KF$ is an abelian extension with conductor dividing ${\mathfrak f}$. This is what Hasse used to call the "Verschiebungssatz" (translation theorem); I seem to remember that this is a purely formal result.

Comment: Ok, of course the extension $K(\sqrt{p^*})/K$ has conductor dividing $p$ (i.e. it is contained in the ray class field $K_p$ modulo $p$). We also have that $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in a ring class field (because of the structure of $Gal(K(\sqrt{p^*})/\mathbb{Q})$), as you wrote in your answer. But why is $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ contained in the ring class field MODULO $p$, i.e $H_p$? A priori, it is contained in the intersection of $K_p$ and a ring class field of conductor $dp$, where $d$ can be taken as the discriminant of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ by Cox, Theorem 9.18.

Comment: The extension $K(\sqrt{p^*})/K$ is only ramified at $p$, so its conductor divides a power of $p$.

Comment: What you say implies that $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in the ray class field $K_p$ of conductor $p$. Then we know that $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in a ring class field (modulo $dp$). Isn't it possible that $K(\sqrt{p^*})$ is contained in $K_p$ and $H_{pd}$ (ring class field of conductor $pd$), but not in $H_p$?

Comment: If you enlarge the conductor, you get bigger fields. The ring class field of conductor $pd$ contains the ring class field of conductor $p$. And conductor $pd$ means that the primes dividing $d$ must ramify.

Comment: Ok, so you say that there are no intermediate fields between $H_p$ and $H_{pd}$ that ramify only in $p$. In other words, the intersection of $H_{pd}$ with the ray class field modulo $p$ is exactly equal to $H_p$.

Comment: The extension $K(\sqrt{p^*})/K$ has conductor dividing $p$. I don't understand why you keep on insisting on enlarging the conductor.

Comment: Because Theorem 9.18 of Cox (which I think is equivalent to your result of Bruckner) says that $L/K$ is contained in a ring class field if and only if $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ has a particular structure (say, generalized dihedral). But in the proof of this, when Cox computes the conductor of the ring class field that contains $L$, he needs to enlarge the conductor. So he is able to prove that $L$ is inside the ring class field of conductor (cond. of $L/K$)$\cdot d$, where $d$ is the discriminant of $K/\mathbb{Q}$. My struggle is to understand why in our case (with $L=K(\sqrt{p^*})$) we can drop $d$

Comment: If, otherwise, your result of Bruckner says that $L/K$ is contained in the ring class field *of conductor equal to the conductor of $L$ over $K$* if and only if $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is generalized dihedral, then of course we are done.